# plc4x hangs on query

Tags: apache-plc4x, plc4x

We are trying to use `plc4x` (`plc4j-driver-s7`, version 0.7.0) to query data from a Siemens S7 PLC.

Here is a very simple example. When I run this it indefinitely hangs when executing the query.

```
String field = "%DB500.DBX4.0:BOOL";
connection
  .readRequestBuilder()
  .addItem("value-1", field)
  .build()
  .execute()
  .get();
```

I'm not 100% sure if the address is correct. Can I assume it would throw an error in case of unknown address? Or would it also just hang? Any tips how to trace this are highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please check our mailing list as well: https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@plc4x.apache.org because we saw a lot of similar topics -> So please look there if this is the same. Thank you! :)

Comment: As I replied on our list, if you provide us with a WireShark capture of your communication I am sure we'll be able to improve the error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue, indeed we managed to implement a fix for your problem. Please update to version 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT (or use the 0.8.0 version as soon as that's released ... which is going to be soon)

Comment: I should mention that the 0.8.0 version has recently been released.